# Why are the edges of my lemon verbana plant turning brown?

Tags: diseases, containers, dryness

My lemon verbana often has leaves that are dry around the edges. It doesn't happen to all leaves, but it happens too often for my liking.

It's been getting plenty of water, not a whole lot of sun (it's been raining and cloudy) but a few hours a day. It's in a pot, planted about two months ago, in planting soil mixed with fertilizer.

Any ideas? Could it just be the weather, or is it possible it has some disease or pest? Here are some picture.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]